# What does the "yours" in "yours sincerely" mean?

Tags: meaning, pronouns, letter-writing

"Yours" is usually a possessive pronoun with an implicit noun. What is the implicit noun in the case of "yours sincerely"?

Answer (score 9):

The "yours" in "Yours sincerely" is a [possessive pronoun](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/yours).  It is a shortening of the phrase "I am yours sincerely" so the implicit noun is "I," who is presumably the writer of the letter.

Now you are asking "I am your *what* sincerely," and here is [an interesting article](http://query.nytimes.com/mem/archive-free/pdf?res=FB0E10FB3B5D12738DDDA80894D1405B808CF1D3) from 1900 that would suggest "friend," although given the traditional valediction of "Your humble and obedient servant," I think "servant" would suffice as well.

What I think is particularly interesting is that the noun *has* been omitted, perhaps specifically to make this closing ambiguous, while simultaneously emphasizing that *whatever* I am with regard to you, it is true and without fault.

Comment: I don't want to seem fussy, but if "yours sincerely" is a shortened form of "I am yours sincerely", it still doesn't explain what "yours" meant. what does 'I am yours' mean?

Comment: @Ham Yeah, thanks, I was editing when you were commenting.  I realized I'd misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Ham and Bacon, It could mean just that - simply 'yours'; friend, supporter, love, etc.. intentionally implicit. However, it seems there are references to servant, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valediction#Formal_valediction : "I am, Sir, your most humble and obedient servant"

Comment: I'm curious of three off-topic things. One is if you can search NYT articles by text queries (I'm guessing so since the whole reCAPTCHA project [aims to kind of OCR it](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/learnmore) (using us)). Two, why does it talk about London? And three, why is there a big white area in the middle? Don't tell me they remove the word games, they're my favorite part.

Answer (score 6):

"Yours sincerely" is a valediction, and the "yours" is a shortening of ["your servant"](http://www.tititudorancea.com/z/valediction.htm)

Edit: Converting the link in my comment:

[Examples:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valediction)

> I beg to remain, Sir, your most humble and obedient servant,
>   A.B.
>
> This form is occasionally abbreviated to
>   Your obt svt,
>   A.B.
>   The phrase et cetera may be used in place of the remainder of the valediction, as in
>   I am, etc.,
>   A.B.
>
> As well as
>   YOS,
>   A.B.

"Yours" doesn't just stand for "your servant". It can for anything from "your friend" to "your benefactor". "Yours" is just  a shortened form for any of these.

Comment: Yep. I'm also searching for more references to confirm this.

Comment: Hm, without references I am not inclined to accept that etymology (because 'the possessive second person pronoun used without a following noun' is perfectly acceptable as etymology of the phrase).

Comment: There's this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valediction#Formal_valediction), but they seem to say most the same thing.

Comment: If one goes back and reads old letters, starting around the 1800s, until the current date, one will see that a full valediction, as in "I beg to remain your most humble and truly obedient servant", has over time become shortened to "Yours truly", and then, simply to "yours".

Comment: @WarrenP It's almost as if they had cellphones.

Answer (score 3):

I thought to quote these 2 posts from Quora, which enlarges on the existing answers:

[User 'Rob Weir' 's answer](http://qr.ae/dHlpA):

> It was common in letters to sign it with a statement of your relationship to the person, e.g.:
>
> - Your faithful Son,
> - Your loving Uncle
> - Your most obedient and humble servant
>
> And so on.   It became quite elaborate in some cases.  For example,
>   J.S. Bach one ended a letter to a patron as "Your Honor's and My Most
>   Particular Highly Honored Mr. Senior's most devoted servant".
>
> Over time and with less social formality, this was shorted to "Yours"
>   with an optional adverb, like "Sincerely yours" or "Affectionately
>   yours" or similar.   It is a social grace, something that does not
>   really have any deep meaning today, only a deep history.

Concerning the grammar, [User 'Mike Mendis' 's answer](http://qr.ae/dHlpA):

> Others have already provided excellent answers. To answer the sub-question regarding the meaning of "yours" specifically, I would point out that "yours" is a **possessive pronoun**. It stands in place of "**your + NOUN**."
>
> So, for example, "This book is `yours`" means "This book is `your book`." In English letters, as other have pointed out, it was customary to end the letter with
>   "I am your loving son" or "I am your faithful friend"
>   or even "I am your humble and obedient servant" (when writing to powerful people or people in high positions such as kings or benefactors).
>
> Over time, these longer phrases were shortened to "**yours**"
>   (just as "`your book`" is shortened to "`yours`" in the example above").
>   Eventually, "I am" was dropped as well, leaving simply "yours" with some appropriate adverb such as "faithfully" or "sincerely" or "truly."